# How to access the jdbc driver from an online applet

Tags: java, mysql, jar, applet, mysql-connector

My applet queries a mysql database, so I included the connector J jar in the eclipse project libraries and my applet runs fine in eclipse, but when i put it on the website, I get an error about that jdbc driver. When I made the jar of my project from eclipse, I don't think that the jdbc driver was included in the jar, so how would I access the jar? Should I put the jdbc jar inside my project jar, or have my project jar access the driver stored in its own jar.

Right now, I am using

```
<applet code="test.class" archive="math.jar" width=830 height=600 ></applet>
```

Comment: Can you also mention the exact error about the jdbc driver?

Comment: *"How would I access the jar?"*  I am glad you chose the answer you did, so for the moment, let's presume the applet also requires a custom PLAF. It would be added to the run-time class-path of the applet in the same way, by referencing it in the `archive` attribute. E.G.  `archive="math.jar,fancy-plaf.jar"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a good idea.  You don't want an applet to access a database directly.  You'll have to expose that port on the public Internet - not a good idea.

A better thought would be to put a servlet in between the applet and the database.  Let the applet make the request to the servlet.  It can deal with security, validation, binding, accessing the database, and marshalling the response.

Comment: What if the database is on the same server as the applet?

Comment: *"What if the database is on the same server as the applet?"*  The applet is run on the client, that is the part that matters.  If the applet can connect directly to the DB, so can any malicious software (or non-malicious software used in a malicious way) chosen by the end user (or anyone who has hi-jacked their machine).

Comment: Ok, ill look into servlets, but for right now, i don't care about malicious people, it probably won't happen, so do you know a way to answer my original question?

Comment: You're wrong about both.  I wouldn't want your app to access my data.  I hope you won't have anything important or belonging to someone else in yours.

Answer (score 0):

Either put all classes from the jdbc.jar into "math.jar", or list it in the archive attribute: `archive="math.jar,jdbc.jar"`.